# Deserialize JSON property starting with @

Tags: c#, json, .net, json-deserialization, datacontractserializer

Im writing a c# console app, where i need get som JSON date from a webapi.
For the most part this works fine, however in one of my JSON responses i get a property name staring with @. I cant seem to figure out how to put that JSON property into a C# object.

My code look as follows:

```
public class AlertResponse
{
    public string @class { get; set; }
    public string result { get; set; }
    public string info { get; set; }
}

public class AuthenticationResponse
{
    public string Access_token { get; set; }
}

class Test
{
    private static HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    private static string BaseURL = "https://xxxxx.xxxx";

    public void Run()
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(BaseURL);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
            new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        AuthenticationResponse authenticationResponse = Login();

        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", authenticationResponse.Access_token);

        AlertResponse OpenAlerts = GetOpenAlerts();
    }
    
    internal AlertResponse GetOpenAlerts()
    {
        var response = client.GetAsync("/api/v2/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/alerts/open").Result;

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            return response.Content.ReadAsAsync<AlertResponse>().Result;
        }

        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} ({1})", (int)response.StatusCode, response.ReasonPhrase);
        }

        return null;
    }
    
    private AuthenticationResponse Login()
    {
        string apiKey = "gdfashsfgjhsgfj";
        string apiSecretKey = "sfhsfdjhssdjhsfhsfh";

        var byteArray = new UTF8Encoding().GetBytes("public-client:public");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray));
        var form = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new Dictionary<string, string> { { "username", apiKey }, { "password", apiSecretKey }, { "grant_type", "password" } });

        HttpResponseMessage tokenMessage = client.PostAsync("/auth/oauth/token", form).Result;

        if (tokenMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            return tokenMessage.Content.ReadAsAsync<AuthenticationResponse>().Result;
        }

        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} ({1})", (int)tokenMessage.StatusCode, tokenMessage.ReasonPhrase);
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

And the JSON i get looks like this:

```
"AlertResponse": {
    "@class": "patch_ctx",
    "patchUid": "afdhgfhjdajafjajadfjadfjdj",
    "policyUid": "dsgafdhasfjafhdafhadfh",
    "result": "0x80240022",
    "info": "fdgdfhsfgjh"
}
```

How can i fix this?

Best regards
Glacier

Comment: Have you tried deserialising to an anonymous object and seeing how it is parsed internally?

Comment: Note: `public string @class { get; set; }` is still a property called `"class"`, not `"@class"` - the `@` just tells the compiler to ignore the fact that the identifier is a reserved keyword; you need to use attributes, as per Michael's answer, to change the serialization name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you are looking for [DataMemberAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.datamemberattribute?view=net-5.0) and [DataContract](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractattribute?view=net-5.0)

```
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

[DataContract]
public class AlertResponse
{
    [DataMember(Name = "@class")]
    public string Class { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "result")]
    public string Result { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "info")]
    public string Info { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Just what i was looking for :) Thanks alot

Comment: @Glacierdk which  answer worked for you? You have accepted the other answer and said thanks to this post

Comment: I clicked the wrong one :S I have corrected it :D

Answer (score 2):

Are you using Newtonsoft.Json or System.Text.Json?

In either cases you should decorate the @class Property with

```
//System.Text.Json
[JsonPropertyName("@class")]
public string class { get; set; }
```

or

```
//Newtonsoft.Json
[JsonProperty("@class")]
public string class { get; set; }
```

Comment: Afaik when i use HttpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsAsync<Object>.result im using System.Text.Json.

However when i try to decorate, the decoration seems to be ignored
I decorate like this:
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;

        [JsonPropertyName("@class")] 
        public string Class { get; set; }

Comment: The code I wrote should work. https://dotnetfiddle.net/eqNQuA Are you shure that you have the correct json serializer set up that is compatible with the corresponding attribute?